# English word for 'make someone feel in debt to you'

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word (at best a verb because the expression in my native language a verb) used to show **disapproval** to describe *when you do or want to do a favor for someone and you want to make that person feel that s/he is indebted to you*.

For example my friend asks me for some money and I start talking about my own financial problems or the fact that this is me who's always helping him out then my friend confronts me with this and says,

> I understand that this is a great favor but please stop [word]ing

Or I ask my colleague to help me and he acts like he wants you to know that he really doesn't have to do it and wants you to know he's doing you a favor. Later you tell your friend about your collegue and say,

> Today I asked my colleague to help me and he did but with some [word]ing.

Comment: For Persian native speakers the word is منت گذاشتن :)

Comment: Interesting... there is an Egyptian word for it too عا َيـِر

Comment: Is that Cairene slang, @JavaLatte ? I think of it as _control_ or _force into line_

Comment: @P.E.Dant, Egyptian is more a dialect than slang, with unique versions for 2,400 of the most widely used 5,000 words. Curious: the other meaning in both Egyptian and الفصحى is calibrate.

Comment: @JavaLatte That _is_ interesting. _Calibrate_ has the sense of _force into an ordered arrangement_ and that's how I thought I'd heard عا َيـِر used. It's easy to see how it can also mean _force to feel indebted._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English, unfortunately, I believe we have no single verb that exactly conveys the negative sense of  the Farsi منت گذاشتن

**Obligate** is a verb which in itself connotes nothing negative. Dictionary.com defines it as *to bind or oblige morally or legally.* Nevertheless, it is sometimes used in a negative sense, thus:

> I understand that this is a great favor but please stop trying to **obligate** me.
>   Today I asked my colleague to help me and he did but not without making me feel **obligated**.

Another useful English word to consider is the adjective **beholden**. Although this word means only *indebted* or *obligated,* it is seldom used except in constructions which do connote something negative:

> > I understand that this is a great favor, but please stop trying to make me **beholden** to you.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps *guilt-tripping*? As in *to lay a guilt trip* on me. It has a sense of making one feel guilty or ashamed.

Comment: This one can make _the_ sense in some contexts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for a verb that describes a rant or tirade the word harangue (or harangued, past tense)comes to my mind. Americans generally use expressions instead so you might hear  "he lectured me" , "read me the riot act",'Jumped my case" or 'guilt tripped me' about ( whatever it was.) He read me the riot act about borrowing money.

Answer (score 1):

**violins!** - (this is a universally understood trope)

> I understand that this is a great favor but please stop [word]ing

*I understand that this is a great favor but please spare me the violins.*

> A sad story is often accompanied on television or radio by doleful
> violin music.  When people say "get out the violin" they are expecting
> a sob story and mean lightheartedly to confer that they have limited
> sympathy for the teller.
> https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100316021906AAym6cU 
> https://citycomfortsblog.typepad.com/cities/2009/06/spare-me-the-violins.html 
> https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090630194940AAaUEu6

---

> Today I asked my colleague to help me and he did but with some
> [word]ing.

*Today I asked my colleague to help me and he did but with some violins playing in the background.*

Comment: +1 Thank you. I didn't know that :) However, the phrase doesn't genuinely deliver the meaning there. It's pretty much like "trumpeting" something with a tint of sadness to it. The meaning I was looking for has a sense of arrogance in it. I actually found a rather close term in English, to deign to do sth, though it's not as flexible as I expected it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I DON'T WANT YOUR FAVOR WITH A "YOU OWE ME A THANK YOU" GESTURE.

i don't want to ask him because he does it with a you owe me a thank you gesture.

i don't want to feel beholden to anyone

Comment: You are not giving an appropriate answer. The OP asks for a particular word, different in meaning from the sentences you give.